# Ec2 calling CLI from user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

When launching an ec2 instance, how does one go about using CLI commands from within a `user data` shell script?

When I SSH into the instance I can run CLI commands and everything works as expected.

I'm assuming the issue is that `user data` is executed as root. When I SSH into the instance and run the CLI commands I do so as ec2-user.

Considering I have to launch an instance every time I want to test my new `user data` script (this takes 3 minutes every try), I'd really appreciate not have to guess and check my way through this one.

any help is appriciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You newly launched instance needs to have access to the command that you're trying to use. I suggest you to add IAM role set up and added to the instance. This will save you the setup of credential etc... Example IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Ubuntu Example userdata

```
#!/bin/bash -x

apt-get update
apt-get install -y awscli # yum install awscli on CentOS based OS
    
REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed s/.$//g)
I_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws_p="$(which aws) --region ${REGION} --output text"
$aws_p ec2 create-tags --resources $I_ID --tags Key=Name,Value=my-test-server --region $REGION
# ............ more stuff related to your deployment ..... #
```

This will install awscli on the system and will tag itself with test name.

See how to add proper [IAM roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Comment: this doesn't work, there is some kind of race condition between the cloud-init scripts and apt-get install

Comment: If you're using different OS than ubuntu, you have to use the proper install command. Like "yum" for CentOS based OSs.
Also the command assume that your user_data is executed by root. Otherwise you can use sudo.